# Text mining with R Tweets

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, hashtag, corpus

I want to use text mining for all the hashtags of my tweet. I have all my data on csv file with Tweets and hashtags separated

```
    file_loc <- "/Users/Desktop/DATA/DATA.csv"
    CSVFile <- read.csv(file_loc, header = TRUE, sep= ";",encoding = "UTF-8")

    #Add new column as hashtags 
    CSVFile$hashtags <- sapply(str_extract_all(CSVFile$Text, "#\\S+"), paste, collapse=" ") 

    #DELETE ALL Lines/Tweets without Hashtags
    CSVFile <- CSVFile[!(CSVFile$hashtags == ""), ]
    # create a corpus of hashtags
    myCorpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(CSVFile$hashtags))
    myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus,
               content_transformer(function(x) iconv(myCorpus, to = "ASCII", sub = " ") ))
```

So, the problem is I have a several hashtags in the same tweet and I wan't to separate them before starting Data pre processing.

Example:

```
[984] #Springparty #rocknroll #fashion #thankyou #cocktails #photographerVmakeupartistÌã                 
 [985] #holborn #redwine #wednesday #goodfriends #funÌã                                                   
 [986] #datenight #indianfood #tamashabromley #foodporn #beers #cocktails #kamasutra                      
 [987] #ThisIsLondon #TakeMeBackToLondon                                                                  
 [988] #gameofthrones
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but are you looking for `strsplit()`? Maybe something like this: `sapply(strsplit(hashtags, " "), paste0)`

Comment: I will try it thanks

Comment: I tried it and I got my hashtags thanks